# Phalcon find with conditions of models relation

Tags: php, model, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I have this model code:

```
class TvguideChannel extends Model{

    public function initialize() {
        $this->setSource('tvguide_channel');
        $this->setConnectionService('db');

        $this->hasMany('code', __NAMESPACE__.'\Tvguide', "ch_code", ['alias' => 'Tvguide']);
    }

    public function getSource() {
        return 'tvguide_channel';
    } 
}
```

And Controller:

```
    $data = TvguideChannel::find();
    $dateDetails = $data->getTvguide(['order' => '$_POST["time"] DESC']);

    $paginator = new PaginatorModel(
        array(
            "data" => $data,
            "limit" => $limit,
            "page" => $curPage
        )
    );

    $items = $paginator->getPaginate();
```

This is not working. How I Can use columns from Tvguide model in controller?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller code will return a `TvguideChannel` instance.
To access the relation you have to use the alias you defined above.

```
$data->Tvguide
```

The above should contain all Tvguide's for this record.

Here is a more detailed example of `hasMany()`:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'id', // The primary key in your main table
    'Models\ServicesVideos', // The Model you are joining
    'service_id', // Foreign key for main table
    [
        'alias' => 'videos', // Alias which you use later to access the relation
        // additional parameters like where, order, limit etc...
        'params' => [
            'order' => 'position ASC',
            'conditions' => 'type = :type:',
            'bind' => [
                'type' => get_class($this)
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

---

**UPDATE**: example of passing parameters to the relation itself.

**Model code:**

```
class Orders extends BaseModel
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Models\OrderDetails', 'order_id', [
            'alias' => 'details',
        ]);
    }
 }
```

**Controller code:**

```
// We want only related records with price higher than 9.00
$order = \Models\Orders::findFirst(17);
$orderDetails = $order->getDetails([
    'conditions' => 'price > 9.00'
]);
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

`find()` method returns a Resulset, which means you can not use directly `$data->getTvguide`. You have to iterate over each record and access its related entries.

```
$data = TvguideChannel::find();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // This will return related guides for each channel.
    $dateDetails = $item->getTvguide(...);
}
```

Comment: but if I want send param for where ? ['conditions' => 'ch_code = $_POST["ch_code"]']. How I can Send this in model?

Comment: If I understood you correct, you want to pass parameters to the `Tvguide` relation? Updated my answer with similar example above.

Comment: Not working.  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::getTvguide()

Comment: Can you show how you call it? Perhaps try with `['alias' => 'guides']` and `$data->getGuides()` ?

Comment: I need get all records, but not FindFirst(17).

Comment: $data = TvguideChannel::find();
$dateDetails = $data->getTvguide(['order' => 'time DESC']);

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find with where from related model then you need to use query builder.